# (Web application) How to restrict user from accessing certain folder through typing in the web address

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, web

Currently I am building a web page that allows the user to upload some pictures to the server. The user can only upload pictures if he is already login.

The pictures uploaded is stored in the server like for example:
pictures/"userid"/some_pictures.jpg

My question is how to restrict other users from accessing the some_pictures.jpg or the "userid" folder by by just simply typing the url address. Only the user that login with that userid can access it's own folder or pictures.

For example:
A user has login with its $_SESSION['userid'] = 1234.
So only this user can access this directory > pictures/1234/some_pictures.jpg
if another user login with 1235 as his userid, he won't be able to access the 1234/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which checks if the user is logged in or not.If he is not logged in, redirect him to the login page.Now if the user is logged in, check if his user id is equal to the user id in `pictures/"userid"/some_pictures.jpg`.
If it turns false, then redirect him to another page such as the homepage.

Comment: Where should I write this function at?